# Resources on Explainable AI

Tags: machine-learning, references, artificial-intelligence

I am looking into the field of explainable AI. The idea is to provide justification for the decision/outputs of Machine Learning Algorithms.

I found some resources online such as: https://www.darpa.mil/program/explainable-artificial-intelligence from DARPA, and this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.00794.

- Can anyone suggest some good examples where Explainable AI was
  applied successfully ?
- Main people in the field ? main research labs ?
- A book ?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend a great book by Christoph Molnar: [Interpretable Machine Learning - A Guide for Making Black Box Models Explainable](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/).

It touches upon both [Interpretable Models](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/simple.html), e.g. Linear/Logistic Regression, Generalized Linear Models (GLMs), Generative Additive Models (GAMs), Decision Trees and [Model-Agnostic Methods](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/agnostic.html), e.g. [LIME](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/lime.html), [SHAP](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/shapley.html).

[Awesome Interpretable Machine Learning](https://github.com/lopusz/awesome-interpretable-machine-learning) links to many interesting publications in the field.

Answer (score 6):

Longer papers which I found when I recently started exploring this topic are:

- [Explanation in Artificial Intelligence: Insights from the Social Sciences](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07269) by [Tim Miller](https://people.eng.unimelb.edu.au/tmiller/) with lots of references
- [The Mythos of Model Interpretability](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.03490.pdf) by [Zachary Lipton](http://zacklipton.com/)

For a more applied perspective and descriptions of concrete applications, you can start with [this recent Science article introducing the topic to a general audience](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/07/how-ai-detectives-are-cracking-open-black-box-deep-learning).

A good list of references can be found on the website of the [IJCAI/ECAI 2018 Workshop on Explainable Artificial Intelligence](http://home.earthlink.net/~dwaha/research/meetings/faim18-xai/#rw) and the [Workshop on Human Interpretability in Machine Learning](https://sites.google.com/view/whi2018/home) held at the same conference.

If you found more information elsewhere in the meantime, I'd be very interested to learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of content coming up everyday. Banking, Pharma, Fraud detection are already using explaibale AI in many ways.

You can get examples/main people( from IBM, Google, Microsoft, FB)/research paper from the github page of these framework.[image: AI framework available in 2020]

we had done very exhaustive literature study to build our own XAI framework-

[exhaustive literature study on XAI](http://machinelearningstories.blogspot.com/2020/06/exhaustive-literature-study-on-xai.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you very new to Explainable AI, this book on Applied Machine Learning Explainability techniques would be the best book for you. It has wonderful code examples and very practical scenarios and dataset presented in the tutorials, where you can gain hands on knowledge on XAI.

Book link - https://amzn.to/3f6v6H3

GitHub link - https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Applied-Machine-Learning-Explainability-Techniques

Hope this helps :)