# entries into machine learning, deep learning, artificial intelligence for social scientists

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, references, artificial-intelligence, social-science

As far as CrossValidated allows users to ask for reference,

- does anyone know (top-notch, authoritative) *books*, resources, or references about ML, DL, or AI for social scientists?

If there are still " *[The Two Cultures: statistics vs. machine learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning)* ", perhaps reflected in StackExchange [Cross-Valited and Data Science](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266067/difference-between-the-cross-validated-and-data-science-se-sites); where to begin learning the ML culture starting from the perspective of statistics/social science?

I am not asking specifically for [Resources on Explainable AI](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349319/resources-on-explainable-ai/355970) but this may be relevant. You may know if you are more familiar with the fields than I.

Comment: From the perspective of statistics or from the perspective of social science? Those seem like rather different perspectives? // What would be the perspective of social scientists? Does that mean light on math? Heavy on applications to social science fields?

Comment: @Dave good question, thanks. Social scientists used to be trained in data analysis using  applied statistics. That is why I implicitly equated the two. I believe social sciences (at least how it has been - it may evolve) falls in the stats par of the two cultures of ML and stats. Does that make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

There is two new book about Machine Learning for Social Research. First is [Machine Learning for Social and Behavioral Research](https://www.guilford.com/books/Machine-Learning-for-Social-and-Behavioral-Research/Jacobucci-Grimm-Zhang/9781462552924) and Second is [Machine Learning for Experiments in the Social Sciences](https://www.cambridge.org/core/elements/abs/machine-learning-for-experiments-in-the-social-sciences/7B7CD20CC383247157A36FBCBE64158B)